# Problem receiving JWT using C# DocuSign SDK

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to receive a JWT from the DocuSign API using the C# SDK. The method that is used in the sample code from DocuSign is

ApiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(clientID,
                            impersonatedUserGuid,
                            authServer,
                            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(privateKey),
                            expiresInHours);

I have done all the pre-work: Creating the integrator key, Creating the RSA Private Key, obtaining consent. In the sample solution - it works, once I fill in the parameters, I receive a token and am able to execute the rest of the program.

However, in my proof of concept project, I do the exact same procedure and the method is returning null. I have been combing my solution for any differences however I can't seem to find the smoking gun. I created a new integrator key, new RSA key, obtained consent. What is interesting is, as a test, I took my new keys that were failing in my proof of concept project and put them into my sample code app - it worked. The exact same values in each project, one worked and the other failed. I even put the string values in directly into the method, again failed in my proof of concept but worked in the sample application.

I notice the sample app was using a different version of the DLL referenced, I changed my project to that version and it still would not work. Any suggestions I would appreciate.

Comment: Yea I could try that. However moving on after the POC, I would probably run into this dilemma again. If I can't find the correct solution than that may be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without seeing your code it's impossible to know how it is different than the sample app. I wonder if you tried the sample code with the new integration key and RSA key you created?
Also, what the other user suggests, take the sample app and modify it so it becomes your code instead of starting from scratch. When you then run into the issue - figure out what was the last thing you change and it probably is the culprit.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I found the problem - ended up replicating the method from the SDK into my code. I found that there was a constructor I missed that was providing the method with a value that I was missing. Taking your advice, I took my code into the sample app and was able to see that. I'll be sure to provide more code next time, I failed to see the bigger picture in the sense that I thought I would just have to feed the method the needed parameters and be done. Thanks!

Comment: glad you found it. Could you mark this as answered please?